# Dart specify list to only contain objects that are extended from another class

Tags: dart

If I have these three classes:

```dart
class Animal {}

class Tiger extends Animal {}

class Lion extends Animal {}
```

Is there a way to create a list variable that would contain objects that extend the Animal class. I know I can use dynamic, but then it could be possible for other types of objects to be inserted into that list.

```dart
class Zoo {
  List<T extends Animal> animals;
}
```

The above code would give me this syntax error:

```
Expected to find '>'.dart(expected_token)
The name 'T' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a type named 'T'. dart(non_type_as_type_argument)
```

Comment: If you don't have a `T` (or other named generic in your class definition) you can just write: `List<Animal> animals;`.

Comment: The base class does have some properties and functions that are shared with all animals, but a specific animal might have some extra properties or functions. So when I call for example the first element in that list. I'm not allowed to call those extra properties or functions since they are not part of the base class.

Comment: That is correct since you cannot know what kind of animal you are getting from the List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused about generics and what `T` actually means in this context. `T` is just a name which you can use across your e.g. class definition if you want to have the same generic type multiple places or when you create a instance of the class.

Your example could e.g. have been written like this:

```
abstract class Animal {}

class Tiger extends Animal {}

class Lion extends Animal {}

class Zoo {
  List<Animal> animals;
}
```

The `List<Animal>` will allow us to put any object which are an `Animal` or extend/implement `Animal`.

By marking `Animal` as `abstract` we prevent instances of `Animal`.

If you want to use `T` we could make it so when we create a `Zoo` we define what type of animals which can live here:

```
abstract class Animal {}

class Tiger extends Animal {}

class Lion extends Animal {}

class Zoo<T extends Animal> {
  List<T> animals = [];
}

void main() {
  final zoo = Zoo<Tiger>();

  zoo.animals.add(Tiger()); // allowed
  zoo.animals.add(Lion());  // not allowed
}
```

Since we in the last example know that the list of animals are made for a specific animal at the time we created the `Zoo` we also get that specific animal from the list when getting an element from it.

Comment: You are correct in the fact that I had misunderstood what ```T``` actually stood for. Thank you for clearing that up, and I also found out a way to fix my issue with help from your post here. When taking one item out of that list and trying to either use one of the extra properties or functions, I would in my case always know what kind of animal it was. So if it is a ```Tiger```, I could just declare a temp variable like so: ```Tiger tempAnimal = animals[index];``` And then I get access to all the extra properties and functions.

Comment: Just be aware that `tempAnimal = animals[index];` are using implicit type casting which are going to be removed in the future when non-nullable by default (NNBD) are coming. You can disable the implicit casting already with: https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#enabling-additional-type-checks

Comment: A better way to handle it is to use `Animal animal = animals[index]; if (animal is Tiger) { } ` since the `animal` variable will then be promoted to the type `Tiger` and you can write you code to handle cases where this is not correct.

Comment: Alternative you can use `tempAnimal = animals[index] as Tiger;` where you explicit are telling that the object you are getting will be a `Tiger`. This will be checked at runtime and fail if that is not the case.